# SQL Server Reporting services Login Issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've deployed SSRS on one of the server. And I am running the service under Domain User account.

Basically the problem is:
I can access SSRS using `url:"IpAddress(or Domainname)/Reports"`, but I am not able to login into it using the domain account as I have already given access to it from manage function in SSRS browser.

But the thing is different after I login through administrator account.As soon as I login, the domain account name(which didn't work before) eventually works. 
And it stops working after some hours and same thing is repeated.

Comment: you may have to login as administrator and give permissions to this user through which you want to access the reports

Comment: i've already given access to the user under domain